# PostgreSQL SELECT query using same structure as a DELETE query

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

With MySQL, I perform a delete with a join as follows:

```
DELETE t1
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.fk_id = t1.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

Before executing the query, I would typical make sure I am okay with the outcome first by viewing the soon to be deleted records as follows:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.fk_id=t1.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

Using PostgreSQL, I believe I should perform the same delete action as follows (EDIT below):

```
DELETE FROM t1
USING t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.fk_id
AND t2.id IS NULL;
```

Concerned that I might not be correct, I unsuccessfully tried the following:

```
SELECT t1.*
USING t2
WHERE t2.fk_id=t1.id
AND t2.id IS NULL;
```

Is there a way with PostgreSQL to perform a SELECT query using the same structure as a DELETE query?

*EDIT - Not even correct since I am effectively performing an INNER JOIN and will not delete any records, and will need to change it as follows.  Still would appreciate an answer to my original question.*

```
DELETE FROM t1  
USING t1 t_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.fk_id=t_1.id
WHERE t1.id=t_1.id AND t2.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a NOT EXISTS condition:

```
delete from t1
where not exists (select *
                  from t2
                  where t1.id = t2.fk_id);
```

That's typically faster than a join and it's also standard compliant SQL.

Comment: Faster, standard compliant SQL, AND it is easy to test results before deleting. Works for me!  Thanks